# Block specific fragments focus

Tags: android

I've two fragments - on top of each other.
I want to block ones fragment focus. How can this be done?

I found that there's `setDescendantFocusability` which can be set to `FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS`. I did get a fragment by finding it (by tag), though, I can not figure out how to set this fragments descendantsFocusability. Any ideas?

Comment: Still looking for answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should get a reference to the fragment's root layout and set it there:

fragmentRootLayout.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);